# Invalid multibyte char(UTF-8)

Tags: ruby, character-encoding, jruby

I am trying compile this Ruby code with option `--1.9`:

```
\# encoding: utf-8                        
module Modd               
  def cpd          
    #"_¦+?" mySQL         
    "ñ,B˜"        
  end    
end
```

I used the GVim editor and compiled then got the following error:

```
SyntaxError: f3.rb:6: invalid multibyte char (UTF-8)
```

After that I used Notepad++ and changed to `Encode as UTF-8` and compiled with this option:

```
jruby --1.9 f3.rb
```

then I get:

```
SyntaxError: f3.rb:1: \273Invalid char `\273' ('╗') in expression
```

Comment: So what are the actual bytes stored in your file?

Comment: What version of JRuby are you using?  1.6.7?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this happen when the [BOM](http://www.unicode.org/faq//utf_bom.html#BOM) gets messed up during a charset conversion (the BOM in octal is `357 273 277`).  If you open the file with a hexadecimal editor (`:%!xxd` on `vi`), you will more than likely see characters at the beginning of the file, before the first `#`.

If you recreate that file directly in utf-8, or get rid of these spurious characters, this should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I created new file with option encoding utf-8 without BOM.Now its working.